# Upload pano image with heading and gps using street View Publish API won't work

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client, google-streetview-publish

I'm trying to upload spherical images on street view using Publish Api.
Upload of image data and place association works well, but whenever i try to upload heading and gps position data to the image server responds "OK" but then no heading nor position were associated to the image.

Here is the php code i use for the last step of info upload, i really don't know where i am wrong.

```
$data['uploadReference']['uploadUrl']=$upload_url;
$data['pose']['heading']=$heading_north;      
$data['pose']['latLngPair']=$latLngPair;    
$data['captureTime']['seconds']=time();    
$data['places']['placeId']=$placeid; 

$data_string = json_encode($data); 


$ch = curl_init('https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photo?key='.$_GOOGLE_API['api_key']);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                             
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                     
  'authorization: Bearer '.$_GOOGLE_API['access_token'],
  'Content-Type: application/json',                                             
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                     
);                                                                                                                   
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

EDIT:

I've implemented the second step as suggested but nothing changes..
Curl response still doesn't contains any error..

```
$ch = curl_init('https://streetviewpublish.googleapis.com/v1/photo/'.$photo_id.'?key='.$_GOOGLE_API['api_key'].'&updateMask=pose.heading');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'authorization: Bearer '.$_GOOGLE_API['access_token'],
        'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
$json_response=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
echo $json_response;
```

EDIT2: this procedure works but google apis are slow and edited data will show up in minutes..

EDIT3 (SOLVED): GET photos (list) has some chache issue. to get the correct value just updated you need to request GET photo (single) to force an effective cache update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the values in a second step with [photo.update](https://developers.google.com/streetview/publish/reference/rest/v1/photo/update). Don't forget to set the updateMask for the values.

Comment: I've implemented the second step as suggested but nothing changes.. see edit in main question

Comment: How do you check the pose data? With a photo.get request?

Comment: I check data by a GET photos request to get a list of photos and associated data.

Comment: image metadata has now changed to a configuration i've previusly uploaded.. is it only so slow to apply changes maybe?

Comment: It depends. Sometimes the changes show up in 5 minutes, sometimes it takes 24 hrs. Occasionally the changes are even lost, and you need to submit it again.

Comment: So google publish api is slow and unstable: cool! I noticed also that my last changes sometimes show up after i submit a new change and then i have to submit another change to see the last one. This "feature" makes the api unusable and this is very sad to me.